# Create pass for passbook in php

Tags: php, passbook

Im trying to create dynamically coupons for my app. I have an PHP Server that create them. But i don't know why they doesn't work on the passbook.

If i create the pass from Terminal it works fine. But in PHP with PHP-PKPass.

I left the code in PHP below it appear in my computer the pass but it doesn't add into the passbook (also if I send it via e-mail)

Im 100% sure that passTypeIdentifier, teamIdentifier, Certificate and WWDR are 100% correctly

Note: all images exists

```
<?php
include ("conexion.php");
require('passpk/PKPass.php');

if (isset($_GET['cupon']) and $_GET['cupon'] != '' and $_GET['cupon'] > 0) {

    $cuponID = $_GET['cupon'];


    $pass = new PKPass\PKPass();

    $pass->setCertificate('./Certificate.p12');  // 2. Set the path to your Pass Certificate (.p12 file)
    $pass->setCertificatePassword('*******');     // 2. Set password for certificate
    $pass->setWWDRcertPath('./WWDR.pem'); // 3. Set the path to your WWDR Intermediate certificate (.pem file)


    // Top-Level Keys http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/Chapters/TopLevel.html
    $standardKeys         = array(
        'description'        => 'Store',
        'formatVersion'      => 1,
        'organizationName'   => 'Store',
        'passTypeIdentifier' => 'pass.store.store', // 4. Set to yours
        'serialNumber'       => $cupon['id'],
        'teamIdentifier'     => '********'           // 4. Set to yours
    );
    $associatedAppKeys    = array();
    $relevanceKeys        = array();
    $styleKeys            = array(
        'coupon' => array(
            'primaryFields' => array(
                array(
                    'key'   => 'key',
                    'label' => "Label"
                )
            ),
            'secondaryFields' => array(
                array(
                    'key'   => 'name',
                    'label' => 'Tienda',
                    'value' => "Name"
                ),
                array(
                    'key'   => 'date',
                    'label' => 'Válido hasta',
                    'value' => "Vigencia"
                )
            ),
            'backFields' => array(
                array(
                    'key'   => 'tienda',
                    'label' => 'Tienda',
                    'value' => "tienda"
                ),
                array(
                    'key'   => 'sucursales',
                    'label' => 'Sucursales',
                    'value' => 'Valido en las sucursales y sus horarios'
                ),
                array(
                    'key'   => 'description',
                    'label' => 'Descripción',
                    'value' => "descr"
                ),
                array(
                    'key'   => 'terms',
                    'label' => 'Términos y Condiciones',
                    'value' => "cupon"
                )
            )
        )
    );
    $visualAppearanceKeys = array(
        'barcode'         => array(
            'format'          => 'PKBarcodeFormatPDF417',
            'message'         => "cupon",
            'messageEncoding' => 'iso-8859-1'
        ),
        'foregroundColor' => 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
        'backgroundColor' => 'rgb(4, 148, 203)',
        'logoText'        => 'cupon'
    );
    $webServiceKeys       = array();

    // Merge all pass data and set JSON for $pass object
    $passData = array_merge(
        $standardKeys,
        $associatedAppKeys,
        $relevanceKeys,
        $styleKeys,
        $visualAppearanceKeys,
        $webServiceKeys
    );

    $pass->setJSON(json_encode($passData));

    //creating a temp file called strip.png
    //generamos un directorio temporal y creamos el strip
    $uniqID = uniqid('', true);
    $dir = './tempDir/'.$uniqID;
    mkdir($dir, 0777);

    //copiamos el archvio al nuevo directorio
    copy('../'.$img, './tempDir/'.$uniqID.'/strip.png');

    // Add files to the PKPass package
    $pass->addFile($dir.'/strip.png');
    $pass->addFile('images/icon.png');
    $pass->addFile('images/icon@2x.png');
    $pass->addFile('images/logo.png');
    $pass->addFile('images/logo@2x.png');

    if(!$pass->create(true)) { // Create and output the PKPass
        echo 'Error: '.$pass->getError();
    }

    //borramos el folder temp
    unlink($dir.'/strip.png');
    rmdir($dir);
}
```

Comment: When you install one of your passes on your device, what do you see in the console (to see this, hook your iPhone up to a Mac, launch Xcode and click Window -> Organizer).

Comment: In the iPhone I can't install it because it appear like cupon.pkpass

Comment: It could be that Safari is downloading the file because it does not recognise it as a pass file - Are you serving it with a `Content-Type: application/vnd.apple.pkpass` header?

Comment: I try sending it via e-mail not safari (I also send it via mail when i create it on Terminal and works perfectly). The idea it's to add it from my own app

Comment: So is there an attachment being created and is that attachment properly being appended to your email?  What do you mean it appears like `cupon.pkpass`?

Comment: I download it from my Mac and send it via mail to my iPhone.

Comment: Posted a fix below - let me know if it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the console output as I attempted to install your pass, I see the following warning.

```
Mar 25 10:45:40 iPhone MobileSafari[279] <Warning>: Invalid data error reading pass pass.cuponice.cuponice/9. Pass dictionary must contain key 'value'.
Mar 25 10:45:40 iPhone MobileSafari[279] <Warning>: PassBook Pass download failed: The pass cannot be read because it isn't valid.
```

Digging into your pass.json, I see that your `primaryFields` dictionary does not contain a 'value' key.

```
    "primaryFields": [{
            "key": "key",
            "label": "30% de Descuento en Persianas"
        }
    ],
```

To fix, change your PHP to add a `value` key to your `primaryFields` dictionary.

```
$styleKeys = array(
    'coupon' => array(
        'primaryFields' => array(
            array(
                'key'   => 'key',
                'label' => "Label",
                'value' => ""
            )
        ),                            //...
```

Comment: Thanks men it works perfectly I eliminte the "value" because I didin't want it to appear. But thanks!